# already defined in obj - C

Tags: c, variables

I had an error of `already declared` because I declared the same variable at two files, So I did like this:

`open_gl.h`

```
#ifndef _OPEN_GL_H_
#define _OPEN_GL_H_
#define SCREEN_SIZE 500
#define SCREEN_POINT 0.7
int position;
extern int openGl(int *argc, char *argv[]);
extern void navigate(const char *routeName);
#endif // !OPEN_GL
```

and I'm trying to use the `position` variable in other files.
but I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2005 "int position" (?position@@3HA) already defined in login.obj    sudoku  C:\Users\nati3\source\repos\sudoku\sudoku\registerPage.obj  1

when I remove the declaration from the header file I get:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2065   'position': undeclared identifier   sudoku  c:\users\nati3\source\repos\sudoku\sudoku\login.cpp 8

and other errors about other files that it wasn't declared.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but all symbols starting with a leading underscore and followed either by another underscore or an upper-case letter (like for example `_OPEN_GL_H_`) are reserved in all scopes for the compiler and standard library implementations.

Comment: Please read at least the beginnings of the [excellent answer by Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/918959) - the answer addresses pretty much *everything*.

Comment: Functions don't have to be declared *extern*.  Variables do.

Answer (score 0):

Declare in one compilation unit only.

In all other declare it as `extern`

example:

x.c

```
int x;
```

y.c

```
extern int x;
```

Comment: I tried it, but I got this error: `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "int position" (?position@@3HA) sudoku C:\Users\nati3\source\repos\sudoku\sudoku\login.obj 1 
`

Comment: Hi, 10x, I declared it also in the source file and it works